# Creating relations between two tables in database in SQLite

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

This is my first question and I hope it is an appropriate one. Since I have limited knowledge about databases I don't know the right terminology and I could not find what I'm looking for.

I've decided to develop a dictionary application for mobile platforms since there are none between two languages I know. What I would like to do is create relations or links between items on two tables. I could not find a feasible method on such a simple task. I'm developing my app on Xamarin.Forms in Visual Studio with SQLite3.

I have two tables for words/phrases in a language with the following simple model.

```
ID | Word
1    X
2    Y
3    Z
```

For instance, when I search for word **house** in **Language 1** I would like to get each word on **Language 2** which has a relation/link to **house**. The result may have only one word or multiple words.

I made a little bit research about this topic but I got lost now. I have found ForeignKey in SQLite but it defines only one relation where I may need 3 or 4 relations with different words. And I thought about creating another relation table between words but that is not going to work in the long run when I need to add or remove words while populating my database. It will be so hard to change/edit relations with ForeignKeys or ID matching.

My question is, is there a platform/application where I can see the relations directly and change them without worrying about IDs or ForeignKeys? Nothing fancy or super detailed. I just want to be able to edit my relations by working with words rather than numbers(IDs). I know that in the background everything will be in IDs.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

I have decided to change my model like this.

Language 1

```
ID | Word | Meanings
1    X      A
2    Y      B
3    Z      C, D
```

Language 2

```
ID | Word | Meanings
1    A      X
2    B      Y
3    C      Z
4    D      Z
```

In the code I will implement a method to split "Meanings" into a string list and search those in the "Word" field of other table. This way, I won't be able to create different entries for homographs (same spelling, different meaning) but it will be easier than ID matching.

Answer (score 1):

I would make a table with all words and the language they belong too. In a second table you can define languages that you can use. And in a third table you can put the translations by matching 2 words.

I suggest matching the relations with a foreign key on the id field. Using words as an indentifier will cause problems with this design if a word excists in more then one language (if you don't want to sepperate words with more then 1 meaning in a language). You can create an unique index on the word/languageId combination. How you create them depend on the technology you use. Plain SQL, Entity framework, etc.

**WordTable**

- id
- word
- languageId - Foreign key on LanguageTable.Id

**TranslationTable**

- id
- wordOriginalid - Foreign key on WordTable.Id
- wordTranslationId - Foreign key on WordTable.Id

**LanguageTable**

- id
- LanguageCode

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but sadly I cannot use the same table for both languages since they don't share the writing systems. I have decided on creating a new field called "Meanings" and match according to their writings.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by writing systems. Do you mean character encoding? If so, is there any reason you can't use UTF-8? Note that 1 word often have more then 1 meaning. This can cause that 1 word in language A will have 2 or more translations in language B. So I think you want your meanings in a different table.